# is it okay to overwrite the php superglobal arrays?

Tags: php

Here's essentially what I'm trying to accomplish. I have an HTML form which is processed by PHP. A user is required to be authenticated to be able to submit this form. However, I do not want the user to loose their work if the session times out while they are working on filling it out.

My thought process is, when I perform my authentication check, if it fails, the authentication module can store the `$_POST` data in the `$_SESSION` array, and redirect the user to the login page. Once the user logs in, the login page can redirect the user back to the submission page, and the authentication module would then see that there is saved `$_POST` data in the `$_SESSION` array, and set the `$_POST` array back to the values that were stored in `$_SESSION`. Then the submission page can process the form data as normal.

I have done testing and verified that it is, in fact (at least in the version of PHP I'm using), *possible* to overwrite the value of the `$_POST` superglobal in PHP. And, in this particular situation, it seems to make a lot of sense to do so. Using this method, no other site code anywhere, other than in the authentication module, would have to be modified for every form on the whole site to take advantage of the "saved post data" feature.

So, I've asked myself if I *could* do this, and the answer is yes. But *should* I? Or are there potential problems with using this method? Part of me says it make a lot of sense, but another part of me worries it might be bad code design. If I shouldn't do this, what would be the proper way?

Comment: Cant see any logical reason to overwrite POST if you already are using SESSION. A boolean OR would allow you to keep same logic in one script if that is your purpose.

Comment: It is OK to do, but as @GetSet states, if its in the session why not check for `$_SESSION['POST_VALS']` or whatever and use that?

Comment: Instead of overwrite the value of the ```$_POST``` you should fill the fields of the form with the values you stored in ```$_SESSION``` and let the user resend the form.

Comment: True, something like `$post = isset($_SESSION['saved_post']) ? $_SESSION['saved_post'] : $_POST`, followed by a simple find and replace of $_POST to $post, would have the same affect. I might very well do that. The only worry I would have is the non-standard way of accessing POST data might confuse anyone trying to read the code in the future. Thoughts on that?

Comment: I'd hate for someone down the road to introduce a bug for forgetting to use `$post` instead of the standard `$_POST`... But It's probably a risk worth taking.

Comment: Anyone who knows PHP, the code as you write it (here, so far) would be self-documenting. You could always insert a comment (e.g. via `// comment here` syntax) to relay intended design, for yourself, which is always a good idea when trying something new

Comment: But using a ternary condition wouldnt be advisable, in this case

Comment: What, are you sure I can't user the `/* Comment here */` or the `# Comment here` Syntax. Just kidding, just thought it was funny you specified the comment syntax. Anyway, thanks for your advise, I'll go ahead and take it. If you want to go ahead and post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I would use a more descriptive name for the variable that you restore the saved data too. Something other than `$post` ... perhaps `$saved_data` or just about anything else. In 6 months when you look at the code again it will probably confuse you with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the comments. I ended up using the following code placed in a common library file used by all pages. The only downside is you do have to remember to use `global $post` in any function or method using the special POST data. But it has the advantage of not being hackish like my previous idea.

```php
    if (isset($_SESSION['authSavedPost'])){
      $post = $_SESSION['authSavedPost'];
      unset($_SESSION['authSavedPost']); // So we don't try to re-post the same data twice
    }
    else{
      $post = $_POST;
    }
```

The authentication check function used on this and other forms, if it fails, will save the current POST data as `$_SESSION['authSavedPost'] = $_POST` so it can later be restored by the above code.

Comment: Im not posting a solution. Glad you on some track. I personally dont like your code structure but if it works, it works. (For now)

Comment: There are serious security flaws in all this. You and a few users? Ok. Consider real validation on login user if more than that like clients

Comment: Security flaws? Care to elaborate?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Why are you at point in life cycle of app to give privileged thru POST. Perhaps a security loophole? Im the one who upvoted beyond negative. Even still you have problems you dont even know about

Comment: Now that that easy problem solved you think you got security solved? You just beginning. Helps to read specs on security

Comment: I am still performing data validation before I save anything in the database if that is what you're asking, this is obviously not the full form handler. I don't see how the remainder of the form handling code is relevant to the issue though; how does this code harm the security of the remaining code? I obviously would like to fix it if there is an issue but I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're getting at.

Comment: So a valid user gets hold of the form data via browser dev tools and just submits what they want since its in POST? Hacker is a *valid* user by definition.

Comment: The form handler already contained protection against HTML injection and SQL injection before this modification was ever made (When it was still running against the raw `$_POST` array.) Are you suggesting that somehow this code breaks that or introduces a new security hole that was not previously present?